# Spring Boot JPA - OneToMany relationship causes infinite loop

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I have a two objects with simple @OneToMany relationship which looks as follows:

parent:

```
@Entity
public class ParentAccount {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private long id;
  private String name;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "parentAccount")
  private Set<LinkedAccount> linkedAccounts;

}
```

child:

```
@Entity
public class LinkedAccount {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private long id;

  @ManyToOne(optional = false)
  private ParentAccount parentAccount;

  private String name;

  // empty constructor for JPA
  public LinkedAccount() {
  }

}
```

I ma using Spring `CrudRepository` to operate with these entities. However, when calling `ParentAccount parent = parentAccountRepository.findOne(id);`, some kind of infinite loop starts happening and hibernate spams this all over the console:

```
Hibernate: select linkedacco0_.parent_account_id as parent_a6_1_0_, linkedacco0_.id as id1_0_0_, linkedacco0_.id as id1_0_1_, linkedacco0_.aws_id as aws_id2_0_1_, linkedacco0_.key_id as key_id3_0_1_, linkedacco0_.name as name4_0_1_, linkedacco0_.parent_account_id as parent_a6_0_1_, linkedacco0_.secret_key as secret_k5_0_1_ from linked_account linkedacco0_ where linkedacco0_.parent_account_id=?
```

I tried changed the fetch type to LAZY but then I get this error:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.berrycloud.scheduler.model.ParentAccount.linkedAccounts, could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

(It seems that it is trying to do the lazy load outside of the transactional context).

This is my CRUD repository:

```
@Repository
public interface ParentAccountRepository extends CrudRepository<ParentAccount, Long> {
}
```

Could someone tell me how to resolve this issue? I would prefer the solution with EAGER fetch. Thank you for any tips

EDIT: here is the schema I am using

```
CREATE TABLE parent_account (
    id BIGINT auto_increment,
    name VARCHAR(80) null,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE linked_account (
    id BIGINT auto_increment,
    parent_account_id BIGINT,
    name VARCHAR(80) null,
    FOREIGN KEY (`parent_account_id`) REFERENCES `parent_account` (`id`),
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Comment: Well, each parent account has several linked accounts. thats it. I dont see how this could resolve into a tree map. The depth is supposed to be 1.

Comment: there is no error in your mapping or schema ... i don't  think your infinite loop problem comes from that ... are you doing anything else in those objects ? some JSON / Jackson annotations maybe ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem solved. I was using a custom `@toString` method in the LinkedAccount which was referencing the ParentAccount. I had no idea that this could cause any problem and therefor I did not include the toString in my question.

Apparently, this was causing an infinite loop of lazy loading and removing this reference fixed the problem.

Answer (score 27):

As the first answer suggests:

> Do not use Lombok's `@Data` annotation on `@Entity` classes.

**Reason:** `@Data` generates `hashcode()`, `equals()` and `toString()` methods that use the generated getters. Using the getter means of course fetching new data even if the property was marked with **FetchType=LAZY**.

Somewhere along the way hibernate tries to log the data with `toString()` and it crashes.

Comment: Lombok was indeed the cause of an infinite loop on in-memory model creation and eventually of the StackOverflowError in my case.

Nevertheless, I find Lombok's getters and setters generation too useful to give up on it entirely. 
Hence, I only disabled Lombok generating _toString()_ by adding my own _toString()_ method to a class that just returned _super.toString()_ - and it solved my issue.

Comment: You can still use Lombok excluding your lazy fetch fields. `@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude={"firstLazyField","secondLazyField"})` and `@ToString(exclude={"firstLazyField","secondLazyField"})`

Comment: This is also nice: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47118403/2202107

Comment: As @Ena stated, you can indeed use the exclusions.
Mind that in lombok you could also use `@EqualsAndHashcode.Include` on field level.
If you do this, DO NOT forget to either remove the class-level `@EqualsAndHashcode` or tell lombok to only include the explicitly included fields by setting `@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)` on  class level.  P.S.: instead of the exclude list on `@ToString`, you could also add `@ToString.Exclude` on a field

Answer (score 1):

As [user1819111](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1819111/user1819111) told, `@Data` from Lombok is not compatible with `@Entity` and `FetchType=LAZY`. I had used `Lombok.Data` (`@Data`) and I was getting this error.

As I don't want do create all get/set, I just put the **Lombok** `@Setter` and `@Getter` in your class and all will work fine.

```java
@Setter
@Getter
@Entity
@Table(name = "file")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "File_Sequence", allocationSize=1, sequenceName = "file_id_seq")
public class MyClass{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "File_Sequence")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "file", cascade = CascadeType.DETACH, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Base2FileDetail> details = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This way worked for me without removing `@ToSring` annotation:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "parent_accounts")

public class ParentAccount {
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"parentAccount"})
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentAccount",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<LinkedAccount> linkedAcounts;
    // ...
}
```

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "linked_accounts")

public class LinkedAccount {
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("linkedAcounts")
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parentAccount_id")
    private ParentAccount parentAccount;
    // ...
}
```

PS: In `@JsonIgnoreProperties` You can also ignore more than one field to prevent an infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

Something like this does not work?

```
@Entity
public class Account {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="manager_id")
    private Account manager;

    @OneToMany((fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="manager")
    private Set<Account> linkedAccounts = new HashSet<Account>();

}
```

Comment: I would have to edit my sql schema (which already exists) to add the manager_id column. Also, spring has its way of doing this automatically so I would like to use the deafault Spring JPA way of resolving this issue

Comment: What is non spring jpa there? By the way, your code works for me, you have something in your database data wrong. Check it twice.

Comment: I edited my question and added the schema I am using. Maybe there is something wrong with that?

Comment: Also: @JoinColumn(name = "parent_account_id") on the parentAccount reference did not do anything (I think that Springs injects this automatically so it is already there)

Comment: I would really like to help you, but I am unable to reproduce. I have the same schema, two entries in linked accounts, one in parent, and I have no loops while querying.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this issue due to a poorly defined Jackson2HttpMessageConverter.

I had done something like the following.

```
@Bean
RestTemplate restTemplate(@Qualifier("halJacksonHttpMessageConverter")
                                  TypeConstrainedMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter halConverter) {
    final RestTemplate template = new RestTemplateBuilder().build();
    halConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(List.of(/* some media types */)); 
    final List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters = template.getMessageConverters();
    converters.add(halConverter);
    template.setMessageConverters(converters);
    return template;
}
```

This caused a problem because the media types did not include all the defaults. Changing it to the following fixed the issue for me.

```
halConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(
    new ImmutableList.Builder<MediaType>()
        .addAll(halConverter.getSupportedMediaTypes())
        .add(/* my custom media type */)
        .build()
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This simple way worked for me. Just use JsonIgnoreProperties .

```
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"linkedAccounts"})
    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinColumn(name = "abc", referencedColumnName = "abc")
    private ParentAccount parentAccount;
```