# How to get a list of entity members which has manyToMany relationship with other entity mapped with JPA?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have tables *Authors* and *Books* (with join table *Authorsbooks*) in database. I created and initiated tables with `MySQL`. I have also made (a standard) `JPA` mapping with two entities Authors and Books using `@manyToMany` and `@Jointable` in one entity and `mappedBy` in the other and connected it to database.

When I try to get all members of *Authors* entity with Java with method `findAll()` it returns an endless sequence: like a first member of authors with list of books, in which a first *Book* contain list of *Authors* where it contain first Book which contain list of authors and so on, endless. How to get only authors w/o field listOfBooks (like I have it in the database table)?

```
@Entity
```

public class Author {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "authorid")
private Integer authorid;

@Column(name = "authorname")
private String authorname;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "listOfAuthors")
private List<Book> listOfBooks = new ArrayList<Book>();
//getters and setters

@Entity
```

public class Book {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "bookid")
private Integer bookid;
@Column(name = "bookname")
private String bookname;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "author2books", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "bookid"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "authorid"))
private List<Author> listOfAuthors = new ArrayList<Author>();

//getters and setters

@RestController
```

@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/authors")
public class AuthorResource {

```
@Autowired
AuthorsRepository authorsRepository;

@GetMapping(value = "/all")
public List<Author> getAll() {
    return authorsRepository.findAll();
}
```

}

```
CREATE TABLE author
```

(
  authorid   INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  authorname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Book
(
  bookid   INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  bookname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE author2books
(
  authorid INT,
  bookid   INT,

PRIMARY KEY (authorid, bookid),
  FOREIGN KEY (authorid) REFERENCES Author (authorid),
  FOREIGN KEY (bookid) REFERENCES Book (bookid)
);

-- Create Author values
INSERT INTO Author VALUES (authorid, 'Sven');
INSERT INTO Author VALUES (authorid, 'Peter');

-- Create Book values
INSERT INTO Book VALUES (bookid, 'Biology');
INSERT INTO Book VALUES (bookid, 'Chemistry');

-- Create author2books values

INSERT INTO author2books VALUES (1, 2);

[image: Entities mapping schema]

[image: Tables creation SQL script]

[Entities mapping/relationship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/737ZB.jpg)

[Database script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKBoo.jpg)

Comment: _You_ might want to show your mapping, then _we_ might be able to help you spot the error.

Comment: your probably triggering lazy loading after accessing a collection of `Author` type

Comment: Please don't post code snippets as images but rather as a code block (nicely formatted text).

Comment: If you could please post the tables schema here too..

Comment: You can take a look here also.. might help.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33234546/spring-boot-jpa-onetomany-relationship-causes-infinite-loop

Comment: CREATE DATABASE testAuthor;
USE testAuthor;

CREATE TABLE Author
(
  authorid   INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  authorname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Book
(
  bookid   INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  bookname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE author2books
(
  authorid INT,
  bookid   INT,

  PRIMARY KEY (authorid, bookid),
  FOREIGN KEY (authorid) REFERENCES Author (authorid),
  FOREIGN KEY (bookid) REFERENCES Book (bookid)
);

Comment: I tried to add images with code. once it worked, another time it wasn't with an error "you need at least 10 points of reputation to add images".

Comment: @NikolayZ It's best if you actually post the written code when asking a question instead of an image so that we can easily copy/paste it for testing. Anyway.. have you seen the link i've mentioned in the comment before? The OP was having a similar problem and it was because he was referencing the relationship entity in a customized toString method, thus incurring in an infinite loop when loading the entities. Please review your code for possible changes like that, and/or post it here so that we can help you find the problem.

Comment: @Israel Merljak Added code. and somebody allowed my pictures.

Answer (score 1):

I was surprised that there was not easy to find a solution for this in my opinion standard situation. I found two ways to solve it.
The first is a bit indirect: Making a query returning entity without including ManytoMany list field like described here:[Spring JPA selecting specific columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22007341/spring-jpa-selecting-specific-columns/22007664).
Second way is more direct but looks quite exotic: using JsonBackReference and JsonManagedReference annotations like here: https://www.keenformatics.com/how-to-solve-json-infinite-recursion/

Answer (score 0):

You can try to mark the relationship Book -> author / Author -> book Lazy loaded to avoid entering an infinite loop :)

> @ManyToMany(fetch = LAZY)

Comment: that's probably reduntant bcoz entity relationships involving collections are by default lazy loaded

Comment: Yeah you're right. it is the default way, but it can't hurt to try right? His mapping doesn't seem to be the problem here anyways. Or perhaps it is..

Comment: Thank you, I tried: but no changes: an infinite loop.

Comment: After long time searching for the answer in Google and Stackoverflow I found one which actually helped. But I don't know if that may give side effects: using JsonBackReference and JsonManagedReference  annotations like here: http://keenformatics.blogspot.se/2013/08/how-to-solve-json-infinite-recursion.html . Maybe there is another way. I need to test those annotations.