# Prevent recursive association in ManyToOne hibernate

Tags: java, hql

It was a while since a worked with ORM on Java and currently looking for an option prevent recursive references in OneToMany-like relationships. Here is trivial sample.

```
@Entity
public class InnerEntity extends BaseEntity {

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private OuterEntity host;

    public InnerEntity() {
    }

    public InnerEntity(String name, OuterEntity host) {
        this.name = name;
        this.host = host;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public OuterEntity getHost() {
        return host;
    }

    public void setHost(OuterEntity host) {
        this.host = host;
    }

}

@Entity
public class OuterEntity extends BaseEntity {

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "host")
    private List<InnerEntity> dataset;

    public OuterEntity() {
    }

    public OuterEntity(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<InnerEntity> getDataset() {
        return dataset;
    }

    public void setDataset(List<InnerEntity> dataset) {
        this.dataset = dataset;
    }
}

public interface OuterTestRepository extends CrudRepository<OuterEntity, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT outerEntity FROM OuterEntity outerEntity LEFT JOIN outerEntity.dataset")
    Collection<OuterEntity> getAll();
}

@GetMapping("/test")
public ResponseEntity<?> validate() {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(repository.getAll(), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

In the result of query `OuterEntity host` again contains reference on `InnerEntity` which initiate reference.

What is the common approach to prevent it?

Comment: It's completely fine. Nothing bad happens :)

Comment: Well, I return this result as is and web page shows me endless json. I didn't check the memory foot print.

If this expected behaviour how to obtain result in traditional form?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16577907/hibernate-onetomany-relationship-causes-infinite-loop-or-empty-entries-in-json. This might help and prevent infinite loop caused while generating json.

Comment: Nope, it's different things. Anyway, thank you for contribution!

Comment: The most common approach is not to create recursive relationships, as they're usually not necessary and they often just make things more complicated.

Comment: If you use jackson for serialization consider using  `@JsonManagedReference`, `@JsonBackReference` https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion

Comment: Gleichmut you shouldn't return Entity to frontend. Map it first to Dto

Comment: Yes, I do, Michal. Just omit it here for simplicity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using jackson you can use jacksons bidirectional mapping:

in `OuterEntity`:

```
@JsonManagedReference
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "host")
private List<InnerEntity> dataset = new ArrayList<>();
```

in InnerEntity:

```
@JsonBackReference
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private OuterEntity host;
```